# How to draw chart with goterm?

Tags: go, charts, terminal

I want to draw a simple chart in the terminal using Go for which I'm trying to use [goterm](https://github.com/buger/goterm). When I run the example code below ([from here](https://github.com/buger/goterm/blob/master/examples/chart_example.go)) my program finishes without any output. Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
    tm "github.com/buger/goterm"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    tm.Clear()
    tm.MoveCursor(0, 0)

    chart := tm.NewLineChart(100, 20)
    data := new(tm.DataTable)
    data.AddColumn("Time")
    data.AddColumn("Sin(x)")
    data.AddColumn("Cos(x+1)")

    for i := 0.1; i < 10; i += 0.1 {
        data.AddRow(i, math.Sin(i), math.Cos(i+1))
    }

    tm.Println(chart.Draw(data))
    tm.Flush()
}
```

Comment: Works for me. What terminal are you using?

Comment: @akond - And you get an actual chart in the terminal? I'm on OSX with Go 1.9. I tried it using `go run main.go` and `go build main.go && ./main`, but with both I get no output. What setup are you on? Do you have any idea how I can debug this?

Comment: I've tried both windows and linux (centos). Both produce some result.

Comment: Tried on the same setup as you and it works.